# Comparing elements in an array, finding the largest sum of the elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I am attempting to write a single function in javascript that compares credit card numbers listed strings within an array.  The function should find the credit card number with the largest sum, and return that number as the original string within the input array. I am completely stuck, and cannot get past this 'undefined' error message. Here is what I have:

```
function highest(inputArray) {
  var sum = 0;
  var currentHighest = 0;
  var largest = 0;
  for (a = 0; a < inputArray.length; a++) {
    var tempArray = inputArray[a].replace(/\D/g, '');
  }

  function sumDigits(str) {
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      sum += parseInt(str.charAt(i), 16);
    }
    return sum;
  }
  if (sumDigits(tempArray) >= currentHighest) {
    currentHighest = sum;
    largest = inputArray[a];
    return largest;
  } else {
    return largest;
  }
}
var numberArray = [];
console.log(highest(numberArray));
```

Comment: can you please share the code that you tried? It is hard to help unless you post some code

Comment: I see undefined code, please provide some we can work with

Comment: @MatthewR please don't out code in comments. Click the [edit] button rather.

Comment: I am trying to post my code that I have...do I do this as a comment? I am brand new to this website, sorry...

Comment: I am trying to use ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-2528-0088-3972', '4252-2788-0093-7978' ,'4556-4242-9283-2260'] as my 'numberArray'

Comment: I am extremely new to javascript. My experience is solely from codeacademy and reading online resources the past 2 weeks....sorry if I am extremely far away from the correct process...

Comment: are you sure that you work with hex numbers "parseInt(str.charAt(i), 16)" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a good number of basic errors in your code.  Rather than break it down, I will simply put the code revision in here.

```
var ipa = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-2528-0088-3972', '4252-2788-0093-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'];

function highest(inputArray) {
  var currentHighest = 0;
  var largest = 0;
  var tempArray = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < inputArray.length; a++) {
    tempArray.push(inputArray[a].replace(/\D/g, ''));
  }
  function sumDigits(strA) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < strA.length; i++) {
      sum += parseInt(strA.charAt(i), 10);
    }
    return sum;
  }

  for (var a = 0; a < tempArray.length; a++) {
    var csum = sumDigits(tempArray[a]);
    if (csum >= currentHighest) {
      currentHighest = csum;
      largest = inputArray[a];
    }
  }
  return largest;
}

console.log(highest(ipa));
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on my understanding of your question, I hope this is what you are looking for.

In addition to doing a basic loop over the array, you can also sort the array in ascending order and simply pick out the last item of the array for your largest credit card number.

Sample Fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/xxo3m8zf/1/

Sample Function:

```
function largestSum(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  return largest = arr[arr.length-1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
'use strict';

// initial array of numbers
let numbers = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-2528-0088-3972', '4252-2788-0093-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'];

// remove "-" symbol
let normilized = numbers.map(number => number.replace(/-/g, ''));

// get sum for each number
let sums = normilized.map(
  number => [].reduce.call(number, (prev, value) => {
  prev += +value;
  return prev;
}, 0));

// find max sum
let max = Math.max.apply(null, sums);

// find position of that sum
let indexOfMax = sums.indexOf(max);

// get card number
console.log(numbers[indexOfMax]);
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down, it makes a whole lot of sense. Since the 2nd and 3rd card numbers have the same sum, how would you have the function return that last listed number (in this case the 3rd card number (index2))?

Comment: according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf, indexOf returns first occurrence of the specified value, so if you have few cards with same sum of numbers, then function returns the first one